# creation of a variable, and assignment of a value to the variable

Tags: bash

From Bash manual, a parameter is set if it has been assigned a value.

1. In bash, are the following two different concepts:

   - a variable exists
   - a variable has been assigned a value, i.e. is set?
2. `unset` removes a variable or function. Does `unset` make a variable

   - become non-existent, or
   - still exists but become not assigned any value?
3. Does `b=` assign a value to variable `b`? Is `b` set now?
4. Does `declare` a variable creates a variable i.e. make a variable become exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable does not exist if it's not set. For example,

```
unset var
echo ${var?"this is not set"}
-bash: var: this is not set
```

The shell displays an *error message* if `var` is not set. The `echo` is not executed. (Check the bash man page for ways to check and assign values to a variable that exists, but may or may not have a value,  or one that doesn't exist.)

The more usual case is often substitution without an error, and would be handled like this:

```
unset var
echo ${var:-This is a new value}
This is a new value
```

Variable exists and has a value. For example,

```
var=123
echo ${var?"this is not set"}
123
```

Variable exists but is empty (`""`)

```
var=
echo ${var?"this is not set"}
```

The echo outputs the value of `var`, which is nothing, followed by its usual newline

Assigning a value is just like this:

```
var=123
echo $var
123
```

declare is used to assign attributes to a variable (check the bash man page for `typeset` or `declare` under the `**shell builtin commands**` for details.